# Pattern matching in Scala with generic return type

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

There are four different types: Location, Language, Technology and Industry. There is a repository for each type that can return a collection of these types. For example a list of Locations. Each type has a name property with type String. There is a list of Strings. which can contain names of Locations, Languages, etc. I would like to write a function to find those typed entities (Location, Language, ...) that match the names of the String list. I was thinking something about like this:

```
def find[T](names: String): Set[T] = {
  val collection = T match {
    case Language => LanguageRepository.getAll
    case Location => LocationRepository.getAll
    case Teehnology => TechnologyRepository.getAll
    case Industry => IndustryRepository.getAll
  }
  // find the elements in the collection
}
```

This is not correct, so how can the querying of the collection be done, and after that how can I be sure that the name property is there?

Comment: If the client code knows the repository type (`find[Language](names)`) then why not just use a passed parameter (`find(names, LanguageRepository`)?

Comment: I would like to avoid have 4 functions with almost the same body, just the type is different in each.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting. Change `find()` to take 2 value parameters instead of a type parameter and a value parameter. The same information is provided either way but one is much easier to code than the other. (Yes, there might still be a type parameter, but it can be inferred.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [algebraic data types](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/algebraic-data-types-adts-in-scala) for this? They can serve as enums. The example:

```
sealed trait Property
case object LanguageProperty extends Property
case object LocationProperty extends Property
case object TechnologyProperty extends Property
case object IndustryProperty extends Property

def find(names: String, property: Property): Set[ParentClass] = {
  val collection = property match {
    case LanguageProperty => LanguageRepository.getAll
    case LocationProperty => LocationRepository.getAll
    case TechnologyProperty => TechnologyRepository.getAll
    case IndustryProperty => IndustryRepository.getAll
  }
  // find the elements in the collection
}
```

Implying that `ParentClass` is a parent class of your `Language`, `Location`, `Technology` and `Industry` classes.

Comment: I was thinking something like this but wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: @Duelist I don't think that makes sense - you use Property as a parameter and as the return type?

Comment: @pme The return type is not `Property`, but `Seq[Property]`. I just replaced `T` from the question to `Property`.

Comment: @Duelist so you would return a list of objects? At least you need to adjust your ADT to `case classes` but then the question is what is the property Parameter?

Comment: @pme Ok then. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an implicit ClassTag value to determine the runtime class you passed

```
case class Language()
case class Location()
case class Teehnology()
case class Industry()

val LANG = classOf[Language]
val LOC = classOf[Location]
val TEC = classOf[Teehnology]
val IND = classOf[Industry]

def find[Z](names: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[Z]): Set[Z] = {
  val collection = ct.runtimeClass match {
    case LANG => Set(Language())
    case LOC => Set(Location())
    case TEC => Set(Teehnology())
    case IND => Set(Industry())
  }
  collection.asInstanceOf[Set[Z]]
}
```

and then

```
find[Language]("")
find[Industry]("")
```

produces

```
res0: Set[Language] = Set(Language())
res1: Set[Industry] = Set(Industry())
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great idea. `asInstanceOf` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: This to me is a better answer of the two. I do not have a luxury of having an additional type parameter when integrating with a 3rd party framework already defined the class and overrides.